# Oracle Database Backup Error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Previously i have used `oracle 10g version`. but today i uninstalled `oracle 10g version` and installed `oracle 11g version`. after that i installed `apex_4.1.1_en` and create new workspace and install apex backups. then i tried to install database backup (i did backup as schema backup). but i couldn't install backup successfully. i couldn't create tables successfully. i got error saying `tablespace does not exist` as below.

```
tablespace 'APEX_11560722039238920' does not exist
```

how could i resolve this? how could i install my database backup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more ways to fix this, depending on how you made the export. If you used the old exp utility you could create a ddl script and change the tablespace name in the script, run the script and redo the imp. Use `imp help=y` to see the cmdline options, look for indexfile.

If you used expdp, the previous fix is valid but you could also use a remap tablespace directive to redirect the table/index creations to the tablespace of your choice. Use `impdp help=y` for the cmdline options needed.

Since this is you own database, the easiest way to handle this is to just create the tablespace that is missing.

```
create tablespace APEX_11560722039238920 datafile '/where/you/want/APEX_11560722039238920.dbf' size 512m autoextend on next 512m maxsize 2g;
alter user your_apex_owner quota unlimited on APEX_11560722039238920;
```

Comment: Do you mean `indexfile` for the `imp` option?